# Why is Jupyter Note using '/' symbol?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[Running Jupyter notebook from Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnjXE.png)

I've used Jupyter notebook before, but it was the actual app not through Anaconda. Why is the '/' symbol showing? And how can I prevent it from showing? Is this a version issue?

I loaded an old project I was working. And this is how it looked before I re-ran it. Once I ran it, it looked like the previous screenshot. [Jupyter Notebook with Pandas Module when ran on actual Jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGO6J.png)

Comment: It's just a formatting indicator that the data continue onto the next line. It's literal-escaping the newline, if you want to be technical. It's not actually in the data, only it's representation when content on a single line is wrapped to the next in order to display it.

Comment: Is there a way to get Jupyter Notebook to display only all of the data on a single line?

Comment: Don't wrap `df` in `print()`. Just write `df` and Jupyter Notebook will display it nicely with HTML formatting, assuming there aren't too many columns (and even then, there are view settings that can be further configured).